# Combining 'orderBy' with another filter in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to order an array by the output of another filter? I have an expression like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="sub in subscriptions">
  {{sub | subscriptionOutput}}
</li>
```

Here `subscriptions` is an array of objects, the details of which are unimportant, and `subscriptionOutput` is a custom filter.

Now, I would like to order this list (alphabetically) by the output of the `subscriptionOutput` filter. How can I accomplish this? I know I can write a function and sort by that, but I'm hoping there is a slicker way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a reasonably slick way to do this:

```
<li ng-repeat="sub in subscriptions | orderBy: $filter('subscriptionOutput')">
  {{sub | subscriptionOutput}}
</li>
```

Only *reasonably* because you have to add `$filter` to the scope somewhere:

```
$scope.$filter = $filter;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe filters together:

```
{{sub | subscriptionOutput | orderBy:"someKey"}}
```

Comment: I don't think this makes sense, `sub` here is a single element of the array, how can you sort that?

Comment: My bad, didn't read the question carefully. As far as I know, there's not a "slicker" way to do it than `ng-repeat="s in subscriptions | orderBy:someFn` or `s in ordered(subscriptions)`.